# Oracle update query very slow

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a rather simple query that gets stuck:

```
UPDATE BRI_PRINT_DOCUMENT pd
SET PRINT_STATUS_ID = 6
WHERE pd.PRINT_STATUS_ID = 1
  AND  pd.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID IN (
    SELECT jd.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID
    FROM BRI_JOBTYPE_DOCUMENTTYPE jd
    WHERE jd.JOB_TYPE_ID = 2);
COMMIT;
```

The following query doesn't help:

```
UPDATE (SELECT *
  from BRI_PRINT_DOCUMENT PD
  INNER JOIN BRI_JOBTYPE_DOCUMENTTYPE BJD
  on PD.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID = BJD.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID
  AND JOB_TYPE_ID = 2
  AND PRINT_STATUS_ID = 1) joined
SET joined.PRINT_STATUS_ID = 6;
```

We have problems understanding the problem as the following query is fast:

```
SELECT * FROM BRI_PRINT_DOCUMENT pd
WHERE PRINT_STATUS_ID = 1
AND  pd.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID IN (
    SELECT jd.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID
    FROM BRI_JOBTYPE_DOCUMENTTYPE jd
    WHERE jd.JOB_TYPE_ID = 2);
```

Any idea what causes the problem?

Although me and my colleague had the problem of the hanging query through sql developer / Datagrip, the problem got magically resolved when the db admin executed the exact same query with Toad.
There was no table lock, the db admin didn't receive any alert of problems and we have no idea what caused the problem.
Thanks Oracle :-)

Note: there are only a few thousands of records in our dev database.

Explain plan:

[image]

Comment: Is another session updating that table and the rows are locked? If so then the query may not be slow; instead the waiting to get a lock on the table is slow.

Comment: @MT0 Not that I know of...

Comment: How did you determine if the `select` query is fast? Did you check that cardinality showed in the `explain plan` is actually the same as counts from the original tables with these filters?

Comment: @astentx It returns almost instantly... based on the tip of MT0 we're checking with the db admin... we tries 3 kinds of queries, they all hang. So it may indeed be a lock problem.

Comment: What is "slow"?  did you run an oracle TRACE on the session?

Comment: Is the plan you're showing from an explain plan or from a dbms_xplan.display_cursor? and how many rows are there in BRI_PRINT_DOCUMENT pd
WHERE PRINT_STATUS_ID = 1?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem got resolved (see update in my question), but there wasn't a clear reason. The update query turns out to be fast, we don't know what caused the problem.

Comment: At a guess, someone manually ran an update in a session and did not commit/rollback the changes or terminate the session and it locked the table. You then tried to run the update in different sessions and it could not get a lock on the table (as it was already locked by the first update in the original session). Eventually, someone closed that first session (or issued a commit/rollback), which released the lock, and now everything else can get a lock.

Comment: @MT0 Yes there must be a logical explanation for this... I'm keeping an eye on it.. Thanks for the suggestion